# cache, does it make sense to have one?

Tags: caching, memory, operating-system

What I mean is: memories are becoming larger and larger, and OS and compilers smarter and smarter. Therefore my question, if I have to read data from file, does it make sense to implement a cache? Isn't the operating system already managing data into memory?

**edit** ok to be more practical, I have 1TB of data sparse in more files, and 180GB of RAM. I need to read some of this data more than once. Does it make sense to implement a cache like LRU, or when I read from file (using c++) the operating system will have been smart enough to have kept these data somewhere so to read them from memory instead of from disk?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not practical, answerable problem. It is rather attempt to open primarily opinion based theoretical discussion

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the language and library you are using. It is highly likely that you are actually already caching things into the memory.

In general, you want to cache things that you are currently managing until you are ready to commit the updated data buffer back into the file on the disk simply because disk I/O is a very slow operation.

On files that are very big, you may not want to cache the entire data due to memory constraints, but you would still want to cache the block of data that you are currently managing.

Here's a general diagram of different means of storing data from the fastest (most expensive) to the slowest (least expensive):
CPU data registers -> CPU Cache -> RAM -> SSD -> Hard Disk -> keyboard, etc..

HowStuffWorks.com has a pretty good illustration of this hierarchy and the entire article itself is actually a pretty good read as well: http://computer.howstuffworks.com/computer-memory4.htm

**EDIT**: There is also another [similar discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716697/a-question-about-cache-of-filesystem?rq=1) that you may want to check out as well.